# Place SVG's relative to each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have two SVG's and I want to place the second SVG in the top right corner of the first SVG.

In the given example, I want to place the exclamation SVG on the TOP RIGHT corner of the first svg. Can someone tell me what changes I should make to the code? I am trying to do it, but the SVG is getting misaligned every time. Any help will be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="18.035334mm"
   height="17.500378mm"
   viewBox="0 0 18.035334 17.500378"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg13826"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="svc.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs13820" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="8"
     inkscape:cx="16.847496"
     inkscape:cy="28.752239"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1440"
     inkscape:window-height="775"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="1"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata13823">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Calque 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-0.99262638,-1.174181)">
    <g
       id="g70"
       transform="matrix(1.0148887,0,0,1.0148887,16.902146,-2.698726)">
      <path
         inkscape:export-ydpi="250.55"
         inkscape:export-xdpi="250.55"
         inkscape:export-filename="new.png"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         id="path3055"
         d="m -6.8492015,4.2724668 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 -0.4288818,0.1085303 l -5.8524037,2.7963394 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 -0.605524,0.7529759 l -1.443828,6.2812846 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 0.151943,0.851028 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 0.06362,0.08832 l 4.0508,5.036555 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 0.874979,0.417654 l 6.4961011,-0.0015 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 0.8749788,-0.416906 L 1.3818872,15.149453 A 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 1.5981986,14.210104 L 0.15212657,7.9288154 A 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 -0.45339794,7.1758396 L -6.3065496,4.3809971 A 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 -6.8492015,4.2724668 Z"
         style="fill:#b388ff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <path
         id="path3054-2-9"
         d="M -6.8523435,3.8176372 A 1.1814304,1.171762 0 0 0 -7.3044284,3.932904 l -6.1787426,2.9512758 a 1.1814304,1.171762 0 0 0 -0.639206,0.794891 l -1.523915,6.6308282 a 1.1814304,1.171762 0 0 0 0.160175,0.89893 1.1814304,1.171762 0 0 0 0.06736,0.09281 l 4.276094,5.317236 a 1.1814304,1.171762 0 0 0 0.92363,0.440858 l 6.8576188,-0.0015 a 1.1814304,1.171762 0 0 0 0.9236308,-0.44011 l 4.2745966,-5.317985 a 1.1814304,1.171762 0 0 0 0.228288,-0.990993 L 0.53894439,7.6775738 A 1.1814304,1.171762 0 0 0 -0.10026101,6.8834313 L -6.2790037,3.9321555 A 1.1814304,1.171762 0 0 0 -6.8523435,3.8176372 Z m 0.00299,0.4550789 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 1 0.5426517,0.1085303 l 5.85315169,2.7948425 A 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 1 0.15197811,7.9290648 L 1.598051,14.21035 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 1 -0.2163123,0.939348 l -4.0493032,5.037304 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 1 -0.8749789,0.416906 l -6.4961006,0.0015 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 1 -0.874979,-0.417652 l -4.0508,-5.036554 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 1 -0.06362,-0.08832 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 1 -0.151942,-0.851028 l 1.443827,-6.2812853 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 1 0.605524,-0.7529758 l 5.8524036,-2.7963395 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 1 0.4288819,-0.1085303 z"
         style="color:#000000;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:medium;line-height:normal;font-family:Sans;-inkscape-font-specification:Sans;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration:none;text-decoration-line:none;letter-spacing:normal;word-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;writing-mode:lr-tb;direction:ltr;baseline-shift:baseline;text-anchor:start;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;marker:none;enable-background:accumulate"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </g>
    <text
       id="text2066"
       y="16.811775"
       x="9.9799767"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.58333302px;line-height:6.61458349px;font-family:Sans;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       xml:space="preserve"><tspan
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:2.82222223px;font-family:Arial;-inkscape-font-specification:'Arial, Normal';text-align:center;writing-mode:lr-tb;text-anchor:middle;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.26458332px"
         y="16.811775"
         x="9.9799767"
         id="tspan2064"
         sodipodi:role="line">svc</tspan></text>
    <g
       id="g3345"
       transform="translate(0.09238801,0)">
      <path
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:10"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="m 4.4949896,11.260826 2.9083311,0 0,2.041667 -2.9083311,0 z"
         id="path964" />
      <path
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:10"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="m 8.4637407,11.260826 2.9083303,0 0,2.041667 -2.9083303,0 z"
         id="path966" />
      <path
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:10"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="m 12.432491,11.260826 2.90833,0 0,2.041667 -2.90833,0 z"
         id="path968" />
      <path
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:10"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="m 7.6137407,5.2082921 4.6083303,0 0,2.041667 -4.6083303,0 z"
         id="path970" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.52916664;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="m 9.9179005,7.2499601 0,2.005449 -3.966671,0 0,2.0028859"
         id="path978" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.52899998;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="m 9.9179005,7.2499601 0,2.005449 3.9666705,0 0,2.0028859"
         id="path986" />
      <path
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.52916664;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="m 9.9095538,7.2512251 0,2.005449 0.0167,0 0,2.0028859"
         id="path982" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

    <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 45.311 45.311" style="enable-background:new 0 0 45.311 45.311;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g transform="translate(0,0) ">
            <path fill="#FFBF00" d="M22.675,0.02c-0.006,0-0.014,0.001-0.02,0.001c-0.007,0-0.013-0.001-0.02-0.001C10.135,0.02,0,10.154,0,22.656
        c0,12.5,10.135,22.635,22.635,22.635c0.007,0,0.013,0,0.02,0c0.006,0,0.014,0,0.02,0c12.5,0,22.635-10.135,22.635-22.635
        C45.311,10.154,35.176,0.02,22.675,0.02z M22.675,38.811c-0.006,0-0.014-0.001-0.02-0.001c-0.007,0-0.013,0.001-0.02,0.001
        c-2.046,0-3.705-1.658-3.705-3.705c0-2.045,1.659-3.703,3.705-3.703c0.007,0,0.013,0,0.02,0c0.006,0,0.014,0,0.02,0
        c2.045,0,3.706,1.658,3.706,3.703C26.381,37.152,24.723,38.811,22.675,38.811z M27.988,10.578
        c-0.242,3.697-1.932,14.692-1.932,14.692c0,1.854-1.519,3.356-3.373,3.356c-0.01,0-0.02,0-0.029,0c-0.009,0-0.02,0-0.029,0
        c-1.853,0-3.372-1.504-3.372-3.356c0,0-1.689-10.995-1.931-14.692C17.202,8.727,18.62,5.29,22.626,5.29
        c0.01,0,0.02,0.001,0.029,0.001c0.009,0,0.019-0.001,0.029-0.001C26.689,5.29,28.109,8.727,27.988,10.578z" />
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
        <g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'd suggest taking part of the second SVG file and merging it into the first and then transforming the bit you want into the place you want it.

Comment: @RobertLongson But I want the height of both the SVG's different, I don't think I will be able to achieve that if I do merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity I'm using a very simplified version of your pen.

I'm transforming the second svg element in a `<symbol>` inside the firse one. Then I'm using the symbol:  `<use xlink:href="#s" width="5" height="5" />`

Since the symbol has a viewBox you can use a width and a height attribute for the use element. In order to position the use element you can also have x and y attributes.

In order to position the use element in the top right corner I'm using a x attribute x="12" where 12 comes from the difference 17 - 5

Where did I got this numbers:17 is the 3rd value in the viewBox of the svg element (viewBox="0 0 **17** 17) and represents the width of the svg element in user units.
As for the 5 it's the width of the `<use>` element in user units

```html
<svg width="18.035334mm" height="18.035334mm" viewBox="0 0 17 17" id="svg13826">
  <defs id="defs13820">
    <symbol id="s" viewBox="0 0 45.311 45.311">
      <path fill="#FFBF00" d="M22.675,0.02c-0.006,0-0.014,0.001-0.02,0.001c-0.007,0-0.013-0.001-0.02-0.001C10.135,0.02,0,10.154,0,22.656
        c0,12.5,10.135,22.635,22.635,22.635c0.007,0,0.013,0,0.02,0c0.006,0,0.014,0,0.02,0c12.5,0,22.635-10.135,22.635-22.635
        C45.311,10.154,35.176,0.02,22.675,0.02z M22.675,38.811c-0.006,0-0.014-0.001-0.02-0.001c-0.007,0-0.013,0.001-0.02,0.001
        c-2.046,0-3.705-1.658-3.705-3.705c0-2.045,1.659-3.703,3.705-3.703c0.007,0,0.013,0,0.02,0c0.006,0,0.014,0,0.02,0
        c2.045,0,3.706,1.658,3.706,3.703C26.381,37.152,24.723,38.811,22.675,38.811z M27.988,10.578
        c-0.242,3.697-1.932,14.692-1.932,14.692c0,1.854-1.519,3.356-3.373,3.356c-0.01,0-0.02,0-0.029,0c-0.009,0-0.02,0-0.029,0
        c-1.853,0-3.372-1.504-3.372-3.356c0,0-1.689-10.995-1.931-14.692C17.202,8.727,18.62,5.29,22.626,5.29
        c0.01,0,0.02,0.001,0.029,0.001c0.009,0,0.019-0.001,0.029-0.001C26.689,5.29,28.109,8.727,27.988,10.578z" />

    </symbol>
  </defs>

  <g id="g70" transform="translate(15,-4)">

    <path id="path3055" d="m -6.8492015,4.2724668 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 -0.4288818,0.1085303 l -5.8524037,2.7963394 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 -0.605524,0.7529759 l -1.443828,6.2812846 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 0.151943,0.851028 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 0.06362,0.08832 l 4.0508,5.036555 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 0.874979,0.417654 l 6.4961011,-0.0015 a 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 0.8749788,-0.416906 L 1.3818872,15.149453 A 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 1.5981986,14.210104 L 0.15212657,7.9288154 A 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 -0.45339794,7.1758396 L -6.3065496,4.3809971 A 1.1191255,1.1099671 0 0 0 -6.8492015,4.2724668 Z" style="fill:#b388ff" />

  </g>


  <use xlink:href="#s" width="5" height="5" x="12" />
</svg>
```